# Problem with .disable modifier in ContextMenu SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I found interesting action in my program:

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var redButton: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { numbers in

                Button {
                        redButton = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Button \(numbers)")
                }.contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        //action code
                            redButton = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Deactivate")
                    }.disabled(redButton)
                    
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If u run this code and press "Deactivate" in contexMenu, contextMenu will be disabled only for 6..10 buttons, this code switching off/on contextMenu element randomly (try increase or decrease Lists elements and press "Deactivate" on random List element).
If U remove List all working correctly with one Button.
Maybe I need work with dispatchQueue.main.async when change redButton status?
What I doing wrong?

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Every row has "priority status" (red, yellow, green) if u choose Red in context menu, after that u can't choose Red status again to this Row (context menu Red disabled)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's seems like bug contextMenu, because im use Menu instead contextMenu and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Correct code:

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var redButton: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { numbers in
                
                    Menu("Actions \(numbers)") {
                        Button("Deactivate", action: {
                            redButton = true
                        })
                        Button("Activate", action: {
                            redButton = false
                        })
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            
                        }.disabled(redButton)
                        Button(action: {}) {
                           
                            Label("Call", systemImage: "phone")
                            
                        }.disabled(redButton)
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).